# How I get data from a Input to run a function in Django

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates

I'm following a Django tutorial and I have troubles getting the data from a input in my HTML.

This is the code from the tutorial:

#### File *views.py*

```python
def buscar(request):

    if request.GET["prd"]:
        producto = request.GET["prd"]
        articulo = Escucha.objects.filter(user__icontains=producto)

        return render(request, "Producto/resultados_busqueda.html", {"articulo": articulo, "query": producto})
    else:
        mensaje = "Nos has introducido nada"
    return HttpResponse(mensaje)
```

#### HTML

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>

    <title>Busqueda de producto</title>
</head>
<body>

    <form action="/buscar/" method="get">

        <input type="text" name="prd">

        <input type="submit" value="Buscar">

    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

And this is the code I try to run:

#### File *views.py*

```python
def suma(request):

    if request.get["first"]:
        first = request.GET["Primer"]
        second = request.GET["Segundo"]

        variable = first + second
        return render(request, "resultado.html", {"variable": variable})
    else:
        mensaje = "lo siento"
    return HttpResponse(mensaje)
```

#### HTML (file *pruebas.HTML*)

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

  <form action="/pruebas/" method="get">

      <input type="text" name="first">

      <input type="text" name="second">

    <input type="submit" value="suma">

    <p>Resultado: {{ variable }}</p>
  </form>

</body>
</html>
```

And the problem I get is:

> AttributeError at /pruebas/
> 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'get'

I really don't know what the problem is. For me the two code parts are similar.

Comment: The `name="first"` is what is passed through as the key, therefore, you access it with `request.GET["first"]` **NOT** `request.GET["Primer"]`.  But the error is *caused* by this: `if request.get["first"]:`, which *should* be `if request.GET["first"]:` with GET in CAPITAL letters.

Comment: Is the file name actually *pruebas.HTML*? (file extension in uppercase) Not *pruebas.html*? A convention over configuration problem?

Answer (score 0):

> And the problem I get is: AttributeError at /pruebas/ 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'get'

> Y really don't know what's the problem, for me the two codes are similar.

No, the codes are not similar, if you look at it correctly, it should be `request.GET["first"]` not `request.get["first"]`.

And also in Html you have named the inputs as `first` and `second` so the view should be:

```py
def suma(request):

    if request.GET["first"]:
        first = request.GET["first"]
        second = request.GET["second"]

        variable = first + second
        return render(request, "resultado.html", {"variable": variable})
    else:
        mensaje = "lo siento"
    return HttpResponse(mensaje)
```